# Filter Holiday Table from Dataset

Tags: vb.net

I already have this for removing weekend from dataset:

```
= DateDiff("ww", Fields!Adj__Date_Received.Value, Fields!QC_Completed.Value, vbMonday)
+DateDiff("ww", Fields!Adj__Date_Received.Value, Fields!QC_Completed.Value, vbTuesday)
+DateDiff("ww", Fields!Adj__Date_Received.Value, Fields!QC_Completed.Value, vbWednesday)
+DateDiff("ww", Fields!Adj__Date_Received.Value, Fields!QC_Completed.Value, vbThursday)
+DateDiff("ww", Fields!Adj__Date_Received.Value, Fields!QC_Completed.Value, vbFriday)
```

Now trying to remove holiday as well. But cant figure it out. I have this table dbo.Holiday_Table that has the data for the holidays. Just need to expression to use. Please help. Thanks!

Comment: Why not do this in SQL? It would be far simpler and perform dramatically better.

Comment: What is the desired result? The amount of days between two dates, excluding weekends and holidays? I'd imagine LINQ would make this much easier if you were insistent on doing this in code (and not the db, as @UnhandledExcepSean rightly suggested), as opposed to adding all these `DateDiff`s.

Comment: What would the SQL look like as an example? I do have that as an option.

Comment: whats the structure of your query to get your data?  what does your holidays table look like?  are you using old school ado in vb.net?  why?